# Как обратиться к элементу у которого нет id и нет class.

Tags: javascript

Задача наверно проста, но в программировании я жесткий ламер.

---

```
<div onclick="func()">
   <div style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

---

Хочется чтобы по клику на div с функцией, менялось свойство display у внутреннего div.
Не ржать :)
Пробовал через this... но он меняет свойство у внешнего div... а хочется у внутреннего. Это вообще реально?

В крайнем можно присвоить class внутреннему div.

Comment: Кстати @ustal getElementsByClassName не работает в IE<9 Я написал универсальную ф-цию в вашем вопрсе [Как задать всем div с одинаковым классом свойство display:none](http://hashcode.ru/questions/113177/как-задать-всем-div-с-одинаковым-классом-свойство-display-none  "Как задать всем div с одинаковым классом свойство display:none")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function func(el){
         el.firstElementChild.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
<div onclick="func(this)">123
   <div style="display:none;">456</div>
</div>
```

Comment: firstElementChild - забавно :) а secondElementChild бывает? или как в таких случаях поступать?
А вообще МЕГА-спасибище :)

Comment: firstElementChild — первый дочерний элементы;
    lastElementChild — последний дочерний элементы;
    nextElementSibling — следующий элементы;
    previousElementSibling — предыдущий элементы;
    childElementCount — количество дочерних элементов.

Comment: @ustal, `el1.childNodes[1]`

Comment: и последний вопрос можно как то для всех div с class="primer" на странице установить свойство display:none; ... и я счастлив :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, children же!

Comment: Мне бы столько же как и Вам надо было для счастья :)  
Средствами JavaScript  

    var classPrimer=document.getElementsByClassName("primer");
    for (i in classPrimer) {
        i.style.display="none";
    };
Средствами CSS  

    div.primer {display:none;}

Comment: @karmadro4 [Пример с childNodes](http://jsfiddle.net/ngdAQ/)

Comment: @ReinRaus, [не надо со мной спорить](http://jsfiddle.net/bugmenot/ngdAQ/3/).

Comment: @ReinRaus - [а так? ;D](http://jsfiddle.net/ngdAQ/4/)

Comment: Ну если намешать узлы и текст, то не.стоит потом удивляться.

Comment: @ReinRaus - LOL, вы html пишите без пробельных символов и без комментариев? В рядочеГ все? :D

Ну если так тогда да, можете юзать childNodes :D

****

@ustal - так я не вам пишу =)

Comment: Ого тут дискуссию развели )) Я уже даже толком не понимаю о чем речь идет. Если спорт из-за типов узлов, то да, [проверять тип узлов конечно надо](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ngdAQ/5/). Только все равно не пойму, чего уважаемый автор @ustal хочет добиться.

Comment: все уже почти работает... осталась одна проблема... кнопка 'закрыть окно' находиться внутри блока который это же окно открывает - видимо при нажатии срабатывают обе функции... причем сначала срабатывает функция зыкрытия, а потом функция открытия... в итоге создается впечатление что 'закрыть' вообще не срабатывает...

а теперь вопрос: как сделать так чтобы клик мышки тормозился на первом div-e и не попадал на второй который находится сразу под ним

объяснил как смог :)

Comment: window.event.cancelBubble=true;
вот это вроде спасло... ща буду кроссбраузерность проверять

Comment: > Ну если намешать узлы и текст, то не стоит потом удивляться.

Ну если путать узлы и элементы, то и код получится *удивительный*. 

http://www.w3.org/TR/ElementTraversal/